# How to get files from a directory on specific condition one file must come after another

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to load data into table using data files. I am using JDBC batch upload. After I load data from test.data into table, I want to validate it using expected-table.data. So in the following method first when test.data comes I want to do batch upload and then it should validate data using expected file but the following code does not work as expeted-data files comes in first iteration and test.data in second iteration. Please help I am new to file programming. Thanks in advance.

```
public static void loadFromFilesNValidateTable(Schema schema, final File folder)
    {

        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles())
        {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory())
            {
                loadFromFilesNValidateTable(schema,fileEntry);
            }
            else
            {
                if(fileEntry.getName().equals("test.data"))
                {
                    BatchUpload.batchUpload(schema,fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());

                }

                if(fileEntry.getName().equals("expected-table.data"))
                {
                    validateData(schema,fileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are there any other files to consider from this folder?

Comment: Hi @Ingo yes there are three files inside folder test.schema, test.data and expected-table.data. I want to use all three in order as it is first schema then data and the expected data file.

Comment: since you have different name for each file. Why not use the name to open the file?

Comment: Define 'after'. Directories aren't ordered. If you want to look for one type of file and then another, do that. You can't rely on the directory doing it for you.

Comment: Hi @EJP how to define after? Sorry I dont know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a FileFilter

```
public static void loadFromFilesNValidateTable(TableDef schema, final File folder) {

    // Process folders recursively        
    for(final File subFolder : folder.listFiles(new DirectoryFilter())){
        loadFromFilesNValidateTable(schema, subFolder);
    }

    // Process data files
    for (final File dataFileEntry : folder.listFiles(new FileNameFilter("test.data"))) {
        BatchUpload.batchUpload(schema,dataFileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    // Process expected files
    for (final File expectedFileEntry : folder.listFiles(new FileNameFilter("expected-table.data"))) {
        validateData(schema,expectedFileEntry.getAbsolutePath());
    }
} 

public class FileNameFilter implements FileFilter {

        private String name;

        public FileNameFilter(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

    public boolean accept(File pathname){
        return pathname.getName().equals(name)
    }
}

public class DirectoryFilter implements FileFilter {

    public boolean accept(File pathname){
        return pathname.isDirectory();
    }
}
```

*Note:* Apache commons-io provides a lot of FileFilters ready to use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/package-summary.html

Comment: You may miss the directory processor for recursive run.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 things to suggest you:
1. Change equals method with matches method. Matches method is the best method to compare
  Strings. 
2. Try to separate the moment in which you do batchUpload from that in which you do
  validateData. Maybe you jump some files. For example the algorithm finds first the
  "expected-table.data" file and then the "test.data" file. In this case it doesn't validate 
  the file. I hope my answer is usefull and I hope I have understood your problem : )

Answer (score 0):

You should change the algorithm to something like this:

```
for (each directory in current directory) {
    loadFromFilesNValidateTable(schema, directory);
}

if (current directory contains file "test.data") {
    batchUpload();
    if (current directory contains file "expected-table.data") {
        validateData();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not code, it's pseudo-code, just showing the main steps of the algorithm. You're supposed to translate it to Java.

Comment: Hi I translated that code into Java but it does not work as expected.

Comment: And? How am I suppose to help if I can't see the code and don't have any description of what the problem is? Edit your question with the code, and a precise description of the problem.

Comment: Hi @JB Nizet I have edited above answer please have a look at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35758/discussion-between-user449355-and-jb-nizet)